# How can I update a variable amount of fields of my user table using Python + FastApi and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am building this API, and I have this User table that has fullname, email, and password as its fields.

I wanted to make a patch function that could update any of these or just two, depending on the user input.

This is what my function looks like (obvionsly it does not work)

```
@user_router.patch('/{id}', status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, response_model=UserSchema)
async def update_user(id: int, data: UserToUpdate, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    async with db as session:
        
        result = await session.execute(select(UserModel).filter(UserModel.id == id))
        user_to_update = result.scalar()

        if result is None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail='Usuário não encontrado')
        else:
            for key, value in data.__dict__.items():
                user_to_update[key] = value

            await db.commit()
            return user_to_update
```

The UserToUpdate classe beimg passed as the type of Data looks like this:

```
class UserToUpdate(UserSchema):
    fullname: Optional[str]
    email: Optional[str]
    password: Optional[str]
```

The UserSchema is just my regular schema required for SQL alchemy to work.

So, my though process behind doing this, is that I wanted to have a Option of my user schema where every parameter is optional, cause if they are not, I will recieve an error if I try to pass json body on my request that does not have the required fields.

Since I want any or multiple of the fields to be updated by the function I wrote this class extending from the user schema, but passing all the parameters as being optional.

When I try to execute the function I recieve the following error: `TypeError: 'UserModel' object does not support item assignment`

Can someone help me out with this? How could I get it done?

Comment: `setattr(user_to_update, key, value)`? SQLAlchemy objects can't be used as dictionaries, they're objects)

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work as well, the error is different tho. `sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.IntegrityError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions.NotNullViolationError'>: null value in column "id" of relation "users" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, Jhon Doe, null, null).`

Comment: That's because your pydantic model will return None when no value is given. You probably want `data.dict(exclude_unset=True)` instead of accessing `__dict__.items()`. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict

Comment: Well, that did change the Error at least, not it says `line 60, in update_user
    for key, value in data.dict(exclude_unset=True):
        ^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: You'll have to have `items()` if you want to iterate over each pair (like you had before). It still returns a dict as it did previously.

Comment: That really did work my man, thanks a lot, you are an angel s2